# Can you have two comparisons in one case statement in a switch?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I was just wondering if I could have two strings I can test for on one case in a switch statement. For example:

```
     switch (month){
        case "Jan": ...

     }
```

This is a regular switch statement, but is there any way to implement a way to compare two strings such as:

```
    switch (month){
       case "Jan" || "January": ....
    }
```

I wanted to know if there is a way to implement this sort of method of code, where I can test for Jan OR January.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly. Instead let execution flow through the `case`s

```
switch (month){
    case "Jan":
    case "January": 
        ...
}
```

If `month` equals `"Jan`" it will hit that case and flow into the `"January"` case.

Comment: Oh I see, so it will still flow into it. Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: If I'm understanding this right, you'd put a break only inside the second case here, not the first, right?

Comment: @Marconius If you had other cases after the `"January"` one that you don't want to be executed, then yes you would put a `break` at the end of the `"January"` case. Obviously, the `break` is unnecessary if there is nothing after this `case`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like you really understood Sotirios's answer. Here's a longer example:

```
switch (month) {
    case "Jan":
    case "January":
        System.out.println("It's January!");
        // Do whatever else
        break;
    case "Feb": case "February": // They can even go on the same line
        System.out.println("It's February!");
        // Do whatever else
        break;
    ...
}
```

This is almost exactly the same in terms of "code room" as your example, except you have to have to repeat the case keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I did a second take on Sotirios' answer after I had left my comment. I read through it too quickly.